# How to add checkbox(input html control) which will be appear dynamically in datatable in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, checkbox, datatable

I want to know how to add checkbox(input html control) which will be appear dynamically in datatable. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Share your code for us to better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the datatable you can't add a checkbox control or any other control. But You can add a column which will be of boolean type (True/False). Which will be what you are expecting.

Comment: I'm writing a E-Leave System.In this system, admin can update the employee's leave balance in textbox(input html control) of datatable.I want to let admin check the check box beside the employee name in one row and enter leave balance in textbox ,I can only let the admin update leave balance. If he/she didn't check any check box,I won't let him/her update leave balance. So,how I can use check box in column of datatable ? Thanks!